# Does inventory management create any sound?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

When I'm trading with my duo/squad, I often wonder... Does dropping items/picking up items create sounds that could give us away?

Comment: I'm pretty sure picking up and dropping items makes noise that everyone can hear.  However, I am finding conflicting sources and videos showing otherwise (though they may be dated).  I'll try and test this with my friends later to see.

Comment: Yes it does make sound that you and your team can hear, however, I do not know if the enemy can hear it

Comment: Picking up items using the "Use" button actually makes a lot more noise than standing over it and dragging it into your inventory.  This is why you see streamers pick up items the way they do.

Comment: I'm not trying to tell you how you can use your votes, but surely if an answer is good enough to accept it's good enough to upvote? I guess you could be out of votes. It's entirely up to you how you vote though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, inventory management does not make any sound, although picking up inventory items does.

Comment: So dropping doesnt make a sound, but taking makes one.

Comment: When you can hear your character creating noise, most of the time, others can hear that if they are close enough to you. (Reloading, changing guns, laying down, standing up, picking things up, etc.) Moving things in your inventory don't create noise so there isn't any for someone to hear.